# onclick even instead of using a button

Tags: javascript, event-handling

Probably simple answer for the ones who know JS, but I am unable to figure it out.

Current situation is that I am using a button to trigger a emoji window, it looks as follows:

```
<button><i class="fas fa-smile"></i></button>

<script>
        new FgEmojiPicker({
        trigger: ['button'],
        position: ['top', 'right'],
        emit(obj, triggerElement) {
            const emoji = obj.emoji;
            document.querySelector('textarea').value += emoji;
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is working but the downside is that a button is surrounding my smiley icon - makes sense of course since I am using `<button>`.

Is there a way to trigger this even without a button? Something like:

```
 <a href="#" id="myemoji" onclick="FgEmojiPicker"><i class="fas fa-smile"></i></a>
```

Comment: EDIT: I removed the 'java' tag. java is to javascript as ham is to hamster: Utterly, completely, entirely unrelated.

Comment: Have you read the FgEmojiPicker documentation?

Comment: yup, there is the JS code I posted in the question - and a short line about 'trigger: 'selector''.

Comment: Then would changing `trigger: ['button'],` to something other than a button work?

Comment: You are probably right, was already experimenting  with that. right now I got:
    <code><a href="#" id="my-emoji" onclick="FgEmojiPicker() "><i class="fas fa-smile"></i></a></code>
with trigger: [code]['FgEmojiPicker'],[code]

Comment: Try using `trigger: ['a']` instead of `trigger: ['button']`

Comment: tried, but not working. Right now I got: `trigger: ['a'],` and `<a href="#" onclick="return FgEmojiPicker();"><i class="fas fa-smile"></i></a>`

But think trigger on a might also be a but too much open. Then it gets triggered on every link on that page

Comment: I would use CSS on the button. `<button style="border: none; background: transparent"><i class="fas fa-smile"></i></button>`.

Comment: tried that also, but I got my textarea setup that <send> is a button also. And when doing it this way, when clicking on the smiley, it was to send the message also

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for you to use 'onclick' or some other type of javascript event. Instead of using this event (onclick="FgEmojiPicker") you have to insert the selector of your element you want to run emojiPicker function with, at this point - 'myemoji'. It should look like this -

```
<a href="#" id="myemoji"><i class="fas fa-smile"></i></a>
<script>
    new FgEmojiPicker({
    trigger: ['#myemoji'],
    position: ['top', 'right'],
    emit(obj, triggerElement) {
        const emoji = obj.emoji;
        document.querySelector('textarea').value += emoji;
    }
});
```

So instead of this event 'onclick="FgEmojiPicker"' you are doing this - trigger: ['#myemoji'].